# The type or namespace name 'DataSetExtensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, reference, sqlclr

I know this is a common error but I have the correct reference to the System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll added to the project and my project is a SQL CLR project built for .net 4.5 and I'm getting the error at the following line:

```
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
```

I also checked the properties for the dll and it is referencing the correct version for the 4.5 dll so what else could possibly be causing this issue? Is this an issue with SQL CLR projects?

Comment: The issue is that there's no namespace named `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`, `DataSetExtensions` is in the `System.Data` namespace, in the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` assembly.

Comment: add this to your using at the top
`using System.Data;`

Comment: Ok I feel silly now. Please make an answer for this and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`System.Data.DataSetExtensions` is an assembly, not a namespace. You just need to add a *reference* to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` (as you say you already have) and then a using directive for the `System.Data` namespace:

```
using System.Data;
```

That will pull in all the extension methods in the classes in that namespace, e.g. [`DataRowExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions).

When you're looking in documentation, always be careful about the difference between namespaces and assembly names - they're often the same, but they're logically independent.

Comment: It's sometimes possible to use `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` as a namespace. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/OOvlLj - do you have any idea why this works?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: Weird. I suspect there's a namespace called that *somewhere*, but I can't find any documentation for it.

Comment: Are there any other gotchas associated with this extensions DLL?  I've followed these instructions and I still can't access the `ToDataTable<T>()` method on my `IEnumerable<T>` object.

Comment: The namespace exists within the assembly, but it contains only two internal classes, therefore undocumented and can be ignored.

Comment: @RLH: `ToDataTable` is not a method from the `DataSetExtensions` dll. It might be one you've found in the internet(f.e. [here](http://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/todatatable) but it's definitely not part of the .NET framework.