# Why doesn't the Lookup that results from GroupBy have Lookup properties?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to understand the `System.Linq.Lookup` class. When calling `GetType()`, the following displays:

```
System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.Object,System.Data.DataRow]
```

- What does the back tick mean?
- What does the `2+` mean?
- What is the `Grouping` class that follows the `2+`?
- Further, in the Fiddle's `Inspect()` method, why does `lookup` have a `Key` property rather than a `Count` and `Item` property?

The ultimate goal is to learn how to bind this to a nested ASP.NET repeater. We've already succeeded by casting the result to a `Dictionary<string, DataTable>`. We suspect, though, that it's possible to bind directory to the `GroupedEnumerable` once we understand its structure.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wTrv2M)

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dt = GetData();
        var enumerable = dt.AsEnumerable();
        var grouped = enumerable.GroupBy(dr => dr["Name"]);
        Inspect(grouped);
    }

    public static void Inspect(IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, DataRow>> grouped)
    {
        LogType("grouped", grouped);

        var lookup = grouped.FirstOrDefault();
        LogType("lookup", lookup);
        LogType("key", lookup.Key);

        var item = lookup.FirstOrDefault();
        LogType("item", item);
    }

    public static void LogType(string label, object v)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + label.PadRight(10) + v.GetType());
    }

    public static DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("StartDate");
        dt.Columns.Add("EndDate");
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = i % 2;
            row["StartDate"] = DateTime.Now;
            row["EndDate"] = DateTime.Now;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Output

```
grouped   System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3[System.Data.DataRow,System.Object,System.Data.DataRow]

lookup    System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.Object,System.Data.DataRow]

key       System.String

item      System.Data.DataRow
```

## Edit

[Forked Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P39rpQ) that retrieves the values from the `GroupedEnumerable`.

Answers in my own words:

- **What does the back tick mean?** The back tick indicates the number of type parameters that a class takes. In this case, it says that the `Lookup` class takes two type parameters.
- **What does the `2+` mean?** The `2` belongs to the back tick not the the `+`. The plus means that we're accessing a class that's nested within another class. In this case, it means that we're accessing the `Grouping` class that's nested within a `Lookup` class.
- **What is the `Grouping` class that follows the `2+`?** It's a class nested within the `Lookup`.
- **Further, in the Fiddle's `Inspect()` method, why does `lookup` have a `Key` property rather than a `Count` and `Item` property?** The `lookup` has a `Key` property because it isn't a `Lookup`; it's a `Grouping` that's nested inside a `Lookup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.Object,System.Data.DataRow]
```

`` System.Linq.Lookup`2 `` is represented in C# as `System.Linq.Lookup<T,U>` (the back tick means the class is a generic and the number is the number of generic parameters).

The `+Grouping` means that there is a class defined inside of the `` System.Linq.Lookup`2 `` class called `Grouping`.

The two types inside the square brackets are the two types that the generic (`System.Linq.Lookup`) closes over.

So the full type, written in C# looks like this:

```
System.Linq.Lookup<object, System.Data.DataRow>.Grouping
```

The type doesn't need an `Items` property because it implements `IEnumerable`, which means the type itself can be iterated over (just like any other `IEnumerable` such as `List<T>`).

Not all lists/collections have a `Count` property, there is nothing that says they have to. You can get the count by calling the `Count()` extension method, but that could cause the entire enumerable to be iterated over, which may or may not have a significant performance cost.

Comment: What does it mean for a class to be defined *inside* another class? Does it mean that it's a public class that has it's definition inside another class? Does the parent class thereby act kind of like a namespace?

Comment: Inside of a class, you can define another class. In the same space you can declare a method or property, you can also declare another type. This can only be done one level deep though, so you can't have a class nested inside of another class that is nested inside of a third class. In C#, the syntax to reference the class isn't any different than if it were another namespace, but in the CLR, it is designated in a different way (i.e. the `+` character).

Comment: Looked at your fiddle, to answer the question why you need the `using` statement for the code to compile, it's because you are using an extension method. In order to use an extension method, the namespace that holds the type that defines the extension method must be "imported" with a `using` statement. It's the same reason that if you remove `using System.Linq`, a lot of methods are no longer available to you for your collections (e.g. `Count()`, `Select()`, `Where()`, etc.).

Comment: The odd thing is, though, that `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` is an assembly not a namespace as far as I can tell. We ought just to be able to use `System.Data`. It's weird. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267788/the-type-or-namespace-name-datasetextensions-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace/28267846#comment48187068_28267846

Answer (score 2):

This is CLR standard type syntax.

- `` `2 `` means that the type has two generic parameters.
- `+` means a type that is nested inside another type.

In this case, it's telling you that the [`Grouping` class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2177) is nested inside a `Lookup` class with two generic parameters.

As you can see from the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2177), the only public property that it defines is `Key`.

Comment: If we're calling into `lookup`, why do we reach the `Grouping` instead of the `lookup`? It seems to me that we should only get to the `Grouping` if we call `lookup.FirstOrDefault().Key`.

Comment: Aha. I get it. The parent `Lookup` class acts a bit like a namespace. The actually Type is `Grouping`. It just happens to have its definition nested inside a `Lookup`. This makes sense. I was thrown off thinking that the type was a `Lookup` whereas it's really a `Grouping`.

Comment: Yes; this is just a nested class.  Note that it inherits its generic type parameters from the outer class.