# Extracting data from datatable with conditions c#

Tags: c#, datatable, conditional-statements

I have a datatable which will contain information from various users, the user for each data is stored as a column in my datatable.

How can I extract the relevant data to show in a datagridview only when the user = msalmon and not something like John?

My table:
[image: My table data]

Comment: `var query=table.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>r.Field<string>("SessionUName")=="msalmon");`

Comment: I got an errorline under "AsEnumerable" when I replaced "table" with my datatable name :/

Comment: You need to import `System.Linq` and add a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` dll. [Read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28267846/284240)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
private void GetRowsByFilter()
{
    DataTable yourDataTable = new DataTable(); //Your DataTable is supposed to have the data
    // Presuming the DataTable has a column named user.
    string expression;
    expression = "user = \"msalmon\"";
    DataRow[] foundRows;

    // Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
    foundRows = table.Select(expression);

    // Print column 0 of each returned row.
    for(int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foundRows[i][0]);
    }
}
```